# How can I convert the block number into the Integer type in substrate module?

Tags: rust, blockchain, substrate

I'm testing the substrate off-chain worker, what I want to do is receive the current block number, and then do some calculation, just like the below code `if (get_block / 10 == 0)`, and I get some error. How can I convert the block number into the Integer type?

#### my code

```rust
use frame_support::{decl_storage, decl_module, dispatch::DispatchResult, debug};

use frame_system::{ensure_signed, offchain};

use sp_runtime::{
  offchain::http,
  transaction_validity::{
    TransactionValidity, TransactionLongevity, ValidTransaction, InvalidTransaction
  }
};

pub trait Trait: frame_system::Trait {}

decl_storage! {
    trait Store for Module<T: Trait> as Runtime_example {
        SubjectCount: u32;        
    }
}
decl_module! {
    pub struct Module<T: Trait> for enum Call where origin: T::Origin {
        fn offchain_worker(block: T::BlockNumber){
            let get_block = block;
            if (get_block / 10 == 0) {  
               debug::info!("print !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");               
            }            
        }
    }
}
```

#### Error logs

```sh
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> /home/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/runtime_example.rs:32:29
   |
32 |             if (get_block / 10 == 0) {  
   |                             ^ expected associated type, found integer
   |
   = note: expected associated type `<T as frame_system::Trait>::BlockNumber`
                         found type `{integer}`
   = help: consider constraining the associated type `<T as frame_system::Trait>::BlockNumber` to `{integer}` or calling a method that returns `<T as frame_system::Trait>::BlockNumber`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> /home/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/runtime_example.rs:32:34
   |
32 |             if (get_block / 10 == 0) {  
   |                                  ^ expected associated type, found integer
   |
   = note: expected associated type `<T as frame_system::Trait>::BlockNumber`
                         found type `{integer}`
   = help: consider constraining the associated type `<T as frame_system::Trait>::BlockNumber` to `{integer}` or calling a method that returns `<T as frame_system::Trait>::BlockNumber`
```

Comment: How is `BlockNumber` defined? It looks like it is currently unconstrained so it could be any type. The crate [num-traits](https://crates.io/crates/num-traits) provides traits for integers and other mathematical properties you can use to constrain it to be an integer type.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I didn't define **BlockNumber**,  the function **offchain_worker** serves as the entry point of the off-chain worker and runs after every block import.

Comment: [`BlockNumber`](https://docs.rs/frame-system/2.0.0/frame_system/trait.Trait.html#associatedtype.BlockNumber) has a lot of constraints, one of which is [`AtLeast32BitUnsigned`](https://docs.rs/sp-runtime/2.0.0/sp_runtime/traits/trait.AtLeast32BitUnsigned.html) from the `sp_runtime` which has a lot of [numerical](https://docs.rs/sp-runtime/2.0.0/sp_runtime/traits/trait.AtLeast32Bit.html) [constraints](https://docs.rs/sp-arithmetic/2.0.0/sp_arithmetic/traits/trait.BaseArithmetic.html). You should be able to do `T::BlockNumber::from(10u32)` for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@kmdreko is right. You do not want to convert the block number to an integer, but convert the integer into a block number and then do the math.

So replace:

```
get_block / 10 == 0
```

With:

```
(get_block / 10.into()).is_zero()
```