# How do you get the current block number in Substrate?

Tags: rust, blockchain, substrate

My question is:

1. How do i capture the current block number?
2. How do I convert the current block number to a u32?

I am trying to write a function inside the template pallet that takes a u32 (input parameter) and adds that number to the current block number.

```
#[pallet::weight(10_000 + T::DbWeight::get().writes(1))]
    pub fn revoke(origin: OriginFor<T>, number: u32) -> DispatchResult {
        let caller = ensure_signed(origin)?;

        // GET CURRENT BLOCK NUMBER
        // CONVERT CURRENT BLOCK NUMBER TYPE TO U32
        // TARGET_BLOCK = CURRENT_BLOCK_NUMBER + NUMBER
        // STORE TARGET_BLOCK

        Ok(())
    }
```

I have read the following document (and many more), but I cannot get the code to work.

- https://substrate.dev/rustdocs/latest/sp_runtime/offchain/storage_lock/trait.BlockNumberProvider.html#tymethod.current_block_number
- https://substrate.dev/rustdocs/latest/frame_system/pallet/struct.Pallet.html#method.current_block_number
- [How can I convert the block number into the Integer type in substrate module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65402395/how-can-i-convert-the-block-number-into-the-integer-type-in-substrate-module)
- https://medium.com/paritytech/utxo-on-substrate-7f0e0576768e

This is a list of my attempts:

```
let y = System::block_number() as u32;
let z = sp_std::alloc::System::block_num() as u32;
let p = Self::block_number();
let h = BlockNumberProvider::current_block_number();
let h: BlockNumberFor<T> = BlockNumberProvider::current_block_number();
let p = BlockNumberProvider::current_block_number() as u32;
target_block = target_block + p;
let x = <T as sp_runtime::offchain::storage_lock::BlockNumberProvider>::current_block_number();
let x = <T as BlockNumberProvider>::current_block_number();
let j = frame_system::Pallet<Config>::block_number();
target_block = target_block + h;
let y = Self::BlockNumber;
let yy = <T as frame_system::Config>::BlockNumber;
let xc = frame_system::block_number();
let current_block = System::block_number()
.saturated_into::<u64>()
.saturating_sub(1);
let u = Number::<T>::get(T::BlockNumber);
let w = T::BlockNumber::block_number();
let n = <T as frame_system::Config>::BlockNumber::block_number();
let m = frame_system::<T>::BlockNumber;
let un = BlockNumberFor;
let current_block_number: u32 = <frame_system::Pallet<T>>::block_number();
let now_block_number = <frame_system::Module<T>>::block_number();
let now_block_number = <frame_system::Pallet<T>>::block_number();
let now_block_number_b: <T as frame_system::Config>::BlockNumber = <frame_system::Pallet<T>>::block_number();
T::BlockNumber;
let xp = now_block_number_b + 10;
let h: BlockNumberFor<T> = BlockNumberProvider::current_block_number();
let x: <T as Config>::BlockNumber = BlockNumberProvider::current_block_number();
let x = frame_system::Config::block_number();
let c = block_number();
let v = <T as frame_system::Config>::BlockNumber;
let x = block;
let q = block.into();
let x: Number<T> = block.into();
let f: u32 = x.into();
let v = 10.into();
let w: BlockNumber_<T> = block.into();
let target_block = target_block + f;
let current_block_number: Number<T> = <frame_system::Pallet<T>>::block_number();
let h: BlockNumberFor<T> = BlockNumberProvider::current_block_number();
let x: BlockNumber_<T> = frame_system::pallet::Pallet::current_block_number();
let y: BlockNumberFor<T> = frame_system::pallet::Pallet::current_block_number();
let z: T::BlockNumber = frame_system::pallet::Pallet::current_block_number();
```

I would appreciate any help you can offer.

Comment: can you please explain why would you add a number to the current block in the first place? what is the benefit?

Comment: @woss Good to hear from you woss. I have answered by own question and posted the code below. The purpose for the implementation was create a function that would only execute if called when [current block number] was within a specific range. The range would be set by the user at an earlier time in the blockchains history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the working code:

```
#[pallet::weight(10_000 + T::DbWeight::get().writes(1))]
    pub fn set_block_delay(origin: OriginFor<T>, block: T::BlockNumber) -> DispatchResult {
        let caller = ensure_signed(origin)?;
        
        let current_block_number = <frame_system::Pallet<T>>::block_number();

        let block_delay: u32 = 10;

        let target_block = current_block_number + block_delay.into();

        ensure!(target_block < block, "fail");

        Ok(())
    }
```

Comment: yep, that's correct way of getting the current block. I suggest having the `ensure` throwing correct `Error::<T>::YourErrorNameHere`

Comment: about the `Weight` i don't think you need the `writes(1)` since there is no write, also the `read` part of the weight is not needed since the `current_block` is in the cache for the duration of the current_block execution

Comment: so the answer is converting u32 to T::BlockNumber? solved your situation but not your question...

Comment: @ClarkLee That is true. I have solved the first of the two questions, but I would still be interested to know how T::BlockNumber can be converted into a u32. Some kind of opposite to into() perhaps? In the above 'failed code' section I added .saturated_into::<u64>(), but that isn't a recognised function (even though it was in another's code).

Comment: Is it possible to use `target_block = current_block_number.checked_add(block_delay.into());` I got a compile error: `u32 not implemented.....BlockNumber`